# Problem adding WordPress/OpenID-login to my account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

I can't add WordPress/OpenID login to my existing Stack Exchange account, why?

Trying to do this, the Stack Exchange user-authenticate page always says:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!", and that the problem is "in our side"..?